# GTA 5 online registration form - password doesn't match?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

It says I need at least 8 letters or some digits - how should I create account have u written any digits

I used the right password and email but it still didn't accept it. Can someone explain why this is? any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want us to create a password for you?

Comment: You need to enter the same password twice

Answer (score 4):

Your password can contain letters, numbers and characters.

The letters A-Z

The numbers 0-9

And these characters ~!@#$%^*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?

Rockstar social club can have issues with certain characters such as / and & so avoid them. More [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200146026-Invalid-Characters-in-Social-Club-Password)

Your password will need to be a minimum of 8 characters in length and contain at least one number or special character. So Pa$$w0rd is valid as it is 8 characters and meets the minimum complexity as it contains special characters and a number. Password also has 8 characters but isn't complex enough as it only contains letters. You can read more about password complexity [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx)
(That password is just an example I wouldn't suggest you use it)

As mentioned by Robotnik you are asked to enter your password twice. The first box will say Password and the second will say Confirm. The same password goes in them both.